# Uploaded data from excel to Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a program written on github.

The author provides an example of running the code with random data.

```
xy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (500, 3)), columns=["x_0", "x_1", "x_2"])
xy["y"] = xy.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)

# set a unique and monotonically increasing index (default index would suffice):
xy.index = pd.date_range("2021-04-19", "2022-08-31").map(lambda x: x.date())
```

Is there an easy way to upload an excel file and get the same labeling as this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.read_excel` to load in an excel file:

```py
xy = pd.read_excel("/path/to/file")
```

It is recommended to store the data in .csv format, though. You can still open it in excel and it is much more efficient with storage.